# How to detect div height after its content is loaded via ajax with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html, height

I've got this strange problem: I got two divs, a menu and a content

```
<div id="menu">
  <a href="#" id="link1"> Link </a>
  <a href="#" id="link2"> Link </a>
</div>

<div id="content">
</div>
```

When you click on a link, the **div is loaded** with the content of different html files:

```
$('#link1').click(function() {
  $('#content').load('page1.html');
}
$('#link2').click(function() {
  $('#content').load('page2.html');
}
```

...and it works :-)

This way the **#content** changes its height because it is "filled" with the html files, and I want that **#menu** takes the same height of **#content**, so I appended

```
$("#menu").height($("#content").height());
```

on the click() functions, but the height of the **#content is calculated before loading the files**, so it doesn't work.
How can I detect when the content is loaded and do the resize after that?

---

PS: The problem is also on page loading: I added

```
$('#prod1').click();
```

within $(window).load, to simulate a click on the first menu item; #content is filled correctly, but the height is miscalculated.. I tried to debug with console.log, tracing the height of the div, but it gave 0, although i put it after the load function.

*The only (bad) solution was to use the **setInterval** function, watching continuously the #content's height and set the same height on the #menu.*

Answer (score 3):

You can use the callback function:

```
$('#link1').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#content').load('page1.html', function(){
      // ...
   });
});
```

However, if you are loading images, you have to listen to the `load` event that is fired for those images, otherwise the height is calculated incorrectly, there are several plugins that you can use like [imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded).

Answer (score -1):

i think you should do something like this `$("#menu").css('height', $("#content").height() + 'px');` You need to apply this after the `#content` is loaded

Comment: The question asked is *how* to apply the change after the external file is loaded. The given code already correctly sets the height, but at the wrong time.